# How to inject array in properties file using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am using SpringBoot "1.5.10.RELEASE" to manage .properties file like this:

```
#Queue1
br.net.enterprise.server.name.1=server1.company.net
br.net.enterprise.server.port.1=4416
br.net.enterprise.server.protocol.1=t3
br.net.enterprise.server.queue.1=DistributedQueue-ERROR
br.net.enterprise.server.sampleRateMinutes.1=2
#Queue2
br.net.enterprise.server.name.2=a.b.c.d
br.net.enterprise.server.port.2=12234
br.net.enterprise.server.protocol.2=t4
br.net.enterprise.server.queue.2=DistributedQueue-ABC
br.net.enterprise.server.sampleRateMinutes.2=5
```

This way I would be able to have 'n' queues configurations.
In my java file I would end up  with this:

```
@Value("${br.net.enterprise.server.name}")
private List<String> names;
@Value("${br.net.enterprise.server.port}")
private List<String> ports;
```

Is there a way to have this behaviour working with spring and Properties files ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use yml file instead of properties?

Comment: Yes, if I can keep this style of config (server1 and server2 isolated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @ConfigurationProperties

Change your properties like this

```
#Queue1
br.net.enterprise.server.1.name=server1.company.net
br.net.enterprise.server.1.port=4416
br.net.enterprise.server.1.protocol=t3
br.net.enterprise.server.1.queue=DistributedQueue-ERROR
br.net.enterprise.server.1.sampleRateMinutes=2
#Queue2
br.net.enterprise.server.2.name=a.b.c.d
br.net.enterprise.server.2.port=12234
br.net.enterprise.server.2.protocol=t4
br.net.enterprise.server.2.queue=DistributedQueue-ABC
br.net.enterprise.server.2.sampleRateMinutes=5
```

Declare two classes like this

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class QueueConfig {

  private String name;
  private String port;
  private String protocol;
  private String queue;
  private String sampleRateMinutes;

}


@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "br.net.enterprise")
public class MyConfig {
  Map<Integer, QueueConfig> server;
}
```

This will create a map like this

[image]

Change 1 and 2 to something meaningful in your properties file. This will be the key in the map, which you can read then from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store values separated by some char ex. comma separated

```
br.net.enterprise.server.name =server1.company.net,server2.company.net,server3.company.net
```

and next read it that way:

```
 @Value("#{'${br.net.enterprise.server.name}'.split(',')}") 
 private List<String> names;
```

Comment: I understand, I am trying to avoid this style because I am using related parameters such as server name, port for example and it would be less confusing if I can manage to get this correlated information all together.